# Failed to perform procedding step after javascriptExecutor performed

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I want to do `Mouse Hover` to perform some task in my application. I did that by using the javascriptExecutor. Before get into my application i tried in some open application. Below is the used code

**Used Code**

```
try{
driver = new FirefoxDriver();  
driver.manage().window().maximize();  
driver.get("http://www.hdfcbank.com/");  
WebElement ele = driver
                .findElement(By.xpath("//li[6]/div/a"));  
String javaScript = "var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');"
            + "evObj.initMouseEvent(\"mouseover\",true, false, window, 0, 0, 0,    0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);"
            + "arguments[0].dispatchEvent(evObj);";  
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;  
js.executeScript(javaScript, ele);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[6]/div[2]/div[2]/div/ul/li[2]/a")).click();
catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
driver.quit();
}
```

When i execute the above code i am able to do the mouse hover but the click action fails. One important thing is it fails to execute the `quit()` command due to that my browser hangs until i close manually. I didn't get any error in my console. I don't know how to debug it.

Any help will be appreciated.

I know the `Mouse Hover` can also be achieve through `Action Builder` class but i need it in javascriptExecutor.

Answer (score 1):

```
catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
driver.quit();
}
```

Your code is saying you only quit, when exception is happening ...
move driver.quit(); outside the catch